# How to make a WiX burn bundle that upgrade a "Lite" version of my product

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7

I have two SKUs of my product. Both are using Burn as a bootstrapper.  I have authored the MSIs in such a way that the Pro version will upgrade and replace the Lite version. But once I've wrapped them in burn, the Pro version upgrades the MSI correctly but the Lite install entry remains in the ARP list.  They are both the same version number and I've set:

```
<RelatedBundle Id="LITE_UPGRADE_CODE" Action="Upgrade"/>
```

In the Pro bundle.

Is there some way to remove the Lite entry?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to do one of the two following things:

(easy): Make the Pro bundle have a higher version than the Lite bundle - upgrades only kick in when the version is higher.

(harder): Use a custom BA to plan the Lite related bundle as `Absent` - you could change the `RelatedBundle/@Action` to `Detect` and when the Lite bundle comes up in `OnPlanRelatedBundle()` change the requested state to `Absent`.  Pro bundle will remove the Lite bundle at the end of the apply phase.

The custom BA is probably the more correct way to solve the problem but will be a lot more work if you haven't already invested in a custom BA yet.

Good luck!